Are there other chat rooms?
Are there other chat rooms besides Bricks.se? If so how do I find them as I would like have options. Can someone help me figure out how to get to them if they exist?

The Chat Rooms are a little transient, there is the main Chat Room (we should probably unfreeze the original and close the new one, although it's never had much traffic), and members with enough privileges can create new ones, or we can move extended comments into specific Chat Rooms.
I think historically we've not tried to replicate the discussion communities available elsewhere on the web that are well established, and the Stack Exchange sites haven't always been great at surfacing the chat features, as we've been about providing great answers to specific questions :)
